# Symfony 4 EasyAdmin - Render association data type in twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony2-easyadmin

Using EasyAdmin in my Symfony 4 app.

Working on *show* view for the User entity.

I want to display all my related (1-many) entities in the show view for User as lists I can style.

The default template for this datatype is `@EasyAdmin/default/field_association.html.twig`.

How can I reference a list of entities for the user (Bookings, Assessment etc).

I have tried adding `{{ entity.assessments }}` the user_show.html.twig but I get error:

```
Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string
```

How can I render these related (associated) entities in this twig template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to iterate your array collection:

```
<ul>
    {% for item in entity.assessments %}
        <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```